# How do you do a Bubble Sort for an Array in C++?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am given a 4 numbers that I have to input them and use bubble sort to sort them from lowest to highest.
This is what I have currently now for the bubble sorting:

```
void bubble_sort()
{
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(num[i]>num[i+1])
        {
            float temp;
            temp=num[i+1];
            num[i]=num[i+1];
            num[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

When I output the the array with the inputs: 3.72, 3.92, 3.46, and 3.86
I get : 3.72, 3.46, 3.46, 0

Comment: `temp=num[i+1];` ==> `temp=num[i];` Better still, `std::swap(num[i], num[i+1])`

Comment: You are only "bubbling" the first value of the array up. To sort the whole array, you need to bubble ALL of them up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49088167/8033585 - notice the double loop

Comment: Bubble sort is O(N^2) which implies it should be loop in loop

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet for "c++ bubble sort example".  Always search before posting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the errors presented in the code are the following

1. Swapping the values in a wrong manner. ( as pointed out in the comments of the question)
2. Letting the value of `j` be 3 in which case it will pick up garbage value in index 4 when `temp = num[j+1]` is run.
3. Only having one `for` loop iterating through the loop only once. Kindly read up on the basics of working and Complexity of bubble sort and how it uses at least two loops from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)

Now the correct answer will be of the form

```
    void bubble_sort(float num[]) {
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(num[j]>num[j+1])
            {
                float temp;
                temp=num[j+1];
                num[j+1]=num[j];
                num[j]=temp;
            }
        }
      }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        cout<<num[i];
    }
```